# What is this beautiful plant in my garden?

Tags: identification

[image][image]

I have no idea if this is a weed or something I planted and forgot about, but it's beautiful looking! Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 5):

Datura, either the cultivated form (*Datura metel*) or the wild form. Considering the look of the flower, even though pretty, I'm pretty sure it's the wild form known as jimson weed (*Datura stramonium*). Below is the wild form. The cultivated form is more colorful and often double.

[image: jimson weed]

[Jimson weed is highly toxic](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Datura_stramonium) and if you have children or pets or if either visit and play in your yard, I'd advise pulling it out. You don't want to take the chance.

Comment: Thank you so much! You are definitely correct - Reading about its medicinal  properties now, but doesn't seem like something wise to experiment with :-)